# Why is this an endless loop?

Tags: c, loops, final

First of all sorry for this, I really think it is a silly question but I've been stuck on this for a while. So maybe you can help me. The problem is I don't truly understand what's wrong in the code. So let's look up.

```
void enter()
{
    int init= 1, end= 2;
    float jump= 0.2;
    create(init, end, jump);
}

void create(int Init, int End, float Jump)
{
    float i;
    int total = 0;
    for(i = Init; i < End; i + Jump)
        total += 1;
}
```

It does not exit the loop and I don't understand why.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, use floats as loop controls. Bad programmer! No biscuit! Also, your `i + jump` should be `i += jump`.

Comment: There's nothing per se wrong with using floating point variables as loop controls, for instance: `for (i=1.0; i=i/2.0; i>epsilon) { ... }`. What's wrong is using floats for things that integers are better used for, particularly comparison for equality with potentially large integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
i + Jump
```

That does not change `i`, it simply evaluates. Change it to this:

```
i += Jump
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: @blackout just so it is more clear i += Jump is equivalent to i = i + Jump which modifies i.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is infinit because variable `i` is not being changed within the loop. Change this statement

```
for(i = Init; i < End; i + Jump)
```

to

```
for(i = Init; i < End; i += Jump)
```

Also maybe there is a sense to define the function as having return type `int` is not there? For example

```
int create(int Init, int End, float Jump)
{
    //...
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As I said silly question.

Answer (score 0):

`i + Jump` this does not modify `i` and hence `i < End` is always evaluated as `TRUE`, as per the initial condition (`Init` being less than `End`).

You need to change to `i += End` to keep incrementing the value of `i.`